# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_16 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 24 but

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to do an image recognition using Keras on Flask. While doing prediction, I encounter this error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_16 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 24 but received input with shape [None, 150, 150, 3]
```

I kinda understand the problem but I'm not sure how to specify the shape. This is on Flask server & I don't do any training here. I use a model that I have trained before on Jupyter notebook.

This is the code

```
def predict(img):
    # Preprocess input image
    img_width, img_height = 150, 150
    x = load_img(img, target_size=(img_width, img_height))
    x = img_to_array(x)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

    # Load model
    dependencies = {
            'precision': Precision,
            'recall': Recall
        }
    model = load_model('model.h5', custom_objects=dependencies)

    # Predict
    result = model.predict(x)[0]
    label = np.argmax(result)
    return label
```

The traceback says it happens on `result = model.predict(x)[0]`. Anyone knows how to approach this error? Tried googling but I don't find any similar error.

**EDIT - Model Summary**

```
Model: "sequential_16"
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense_96 (Dense)             (None, 32)                800
_________________________________________________________________
dense_97 (Dense)             (None, 1024)              33792
_________________________________________________________________
dense_98 (Dense)             (None, 512)               524800
_________________________________________________________________
dense_99 (Dense)             (None, 256)               131328
_________________________________________________________________
dense_100 (Dense)            (None, 128)               32896
_________________________________________________________________
dense_101 (Dense)            (None, 3)                 387
_________________________________________________________________
activation_16 (Activation)   (None, 3)                 0
=================================================================
Total params: 724,003
Trainable params: 724,003
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Can you run model.summary() and send the output?

Comment: @hhaefliger Done. Just updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your input shape is wrong. The input layer isn't shown in the model summary but it says that the first layer has 800 parameters.

This tells me that your input layer has dimensions [None, 24] because 24 * 32 (weights) + 32 (biases) = 800.

When you add the first dense layer it should be

model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(150,150,3))

Comment: So, should I retrain the model? Would it create another problem to another layer?

Comment: If you managed to train the model with the current layers it means that your training and prediction data isn't the same shape

Comment: But yes you should change this and then retrain, it shouldn't break anything but it will add a lot more parameters

Comment: There's another error while training. It actually needs the shape of [None,24]. `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape [None, 24]`

Comment: Yes, this is because your training data is not the same shape as the data for which you are predicting

Comment: I can't retrain it. Changing the first layer for retraining gave me that error. Any other solution?